# VideoJS play HLS manifest with CUE-OUT, CUE-OUT-CONT , CUE-IN tags, how to listen for all cue events?

Tags: video.js, cue-points

VideoJS player and listen for HLS `CUE-OUT:Duration=19.2`, `CUE-OUT-CONT:ElapsedTime=11.52,Duration=19.2`, `CUE-IN` events?

This example almost works but it does not submit anything on CUE-IN and possibly few events from CUE-OUT-CONT but definitely not all instances. It'ss only CUE-OUT happening as expected.

Also how to read `@Duration, @ElapsedTime` CUE attributes?

CUE-OUT=Adbreak start, CUE-OUT-CONT=Adbreak already started and continues, CUE-IN=Adbreak end.

https://github.com/videojs/http-streaming#usecuetags

```
var options={
  muted    : true
  ,autoplay: true
  ,controls:true
  ,hls: { enableLowInitialPlaylist: false, limitRenditionByPlayerDimensions: false }
  ,html5: { 
     nativeTextTracks: false
     ,vhs: { 
       useCueTags: true
     } 
   }
};   
       
player = videojs(videoId, options);
player.src({ 
  "src"  : url
  ,"type" : "application/x-mpegURL"  // "application/vnd.apple.mpegurl"
}); 

player.on(player, ["loadedmetadata"], function(evt) { 
  var textTracks = player.textTracks();
  for(var idx=0; idx < textTracks.length; idx++) {
    var track = textTracks[idx];
    if (track.label==='ad-cues') {
      track.addEventListener('cuechange', function(evt) {
        onCueEvent(evt, player, track);
      });
    }
  }
});

function onCueEvent(evt, player, track) {
  console.log("onCueEvent, activeCues="+track.activeCues.length);
  for(var idx=0; idx<track.activeCues.length; idx++) {
    var cue = track.activeCues[idx];
    console.log("Cue "+cue.startTime + " - " + cue.endTime
       + ", currentTime="+player.currentTime()
       //+ ", "+cue.text
       + ", "+cue.value.dateTimeString
       + ", "+cue.value.uri
    );
    console.log(cue);
  } 
}
```

Example manifest

```
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2023-11-14T12:34:45.120Z
#EXTINF:3.84,
94.m4s

#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2023-11-14T12:34:48.960Z
#EXT-X-CUE-OUT:Duration=19.2
#EXTINF:3.84,
95.m4s
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2023-11-14T12:34:52.800Z
#EXT-X-CUE-OUT-CONT:ElapsedTime=3.84,Duration=19.2
#EXTINF:3.84,
96.m4s
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2023-11-14T12:34:56.640Z
#EXT-X-CUE-OUT-CONT:ElapsedTime=7.68,Duration=19.2
#EXTINF:3.84,
97.m4s
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2023-11-14T12:35:00.480Z
#EXT-X-CUE-OUT-CONT:ElapsedTime=11.52,Duration=19.2
#EXTINF:3.84,
98.m4s
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2023-11-14T12:35:04.320Z
#EXT-X-CUE-OUT-CONT:ElapsedTime=15.36,Duration=19.2
#EXTINF:3.84,
99.m4s

#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2023-11-14T12:35:08.160Z
#EXT-X-CUE-IN
#EXTINF:3.84,
100.m4s
```